# Insertion of Piyutim

Tags: song-poetry, nusach-ashkenaz, yotzrot

In the Minhag Rheinus, we have piyutim which are added by ma'ariv and shacharit on yom tov, as well as on certain Shabbatot. While I am aware of the position of some of them (Yotzer, Ofan, Zulat, kerovot) I am unaware of the actual position certain of the others, namely the ones by Ma'ariv and the Ahavah (the only fromm schul in my area being a Chabad). Is there a chart anywhere which lists the positions of the remaining piyutim?

Comment: By "position", do you mean to ask precisely where within the _b'racha_ it's inserted?

Comment: Which siddurim/machzorim have you checked? Which piyutim do you mean? Anything that can be checked in the Rudelheim or Goldschmidt?

Comment: @msh210, yes, for example, should an ahavah go before or after baruch yotzer hameorot; if before between which pasukim

Comment: @Matt, I own only two of the 5 volumes of shalosh regalim machzorim, a Rödelheim for Shmini Atzeret/Simchat Torah, and a Sulzbach for Shavuot. Due to their advanced ages (over 140 years) and low-quality paper, I am always uncomfortable leafing through them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ashkenaz today [the situation was different in different communities in the past]:

- Me'ora - Before or chodosh.
- Ahava - different minhogim, either before v'keiravtanu or before l'hodos lecho.
- Maarivim

  - Short piyut before end of first berocho,
  - Same with second;

    - long piyut before בגילה ברינה בשמחה רבה ואמרו כלם,
    - short piyut before זה צור ישענו פצו פה ואמרו [insted of זה א-לי ענו ואמרו],
  - short piyut before end of that berocho,
  - and short or long piyut before the end of השכיבנו.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya!  The question was asking for the existence of a chart.  Also, in general, providing sources improves the value of answers here, since I'm sure you're great but none of us know you.

Comment: They are called Ma'arovos. Also, who puts an Ahavoh before l'hodos lecho?

Comment: @JoshuaPearl The Rodelheim that was printed about 15 years ago has piyutim in the back. The instructions clearly indicate that the _ahavoh_ for  the week before _shavu'oth_ and 9 _Av_ (the only _ahavoh_ in the German _nusach_) is inserted at this point. I am a member of KAJ in Washington Heights, and that is what we do as well.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss, do you have a link to where I could get this Rödelheim. PS. Do you know places to stay near Breuer's if one is in town for a schabbos?

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss You are correct. I have recently seen this verion of the Avodas Yisroel.